# Using QWidgets launching an Android App looks different when lauched via PC that when doing so via the phone

Tags: android, qt

When I create any normal app using Qt and QWidgets and compile it for android downloading it to my phone, there is wild difference on the app's appearance when lauched from my PC (when I compile download it or just start it if no changes were made) as compared when launched from my phone.

When lauched from my PC it looks like this:
[image: Lauched from PC]

And launched from my phone thereafter:[image]

Anyone know why this is and how to solve it?

Comment: Are you sure about your analysis? I personnaly experienced random switch between the two displays. As if at some point a display style was failing to be loaded by the app....randomly.

Comment: Yes. I never got the "right view" when launching from the Cell phone. And I've never gotten the "wrong view" when launching pressing the play button  (which essentially reinstalls the app every time)

Comment: Wierd, I "almost" always get the right display, no matter how the app is started.

Comment: Could be the different versions of Qt/GCC/OS? I'm using Qt5.7.0 with GCC-4.9 on an x64 Centos7 Platform with QtCreator 4.1.0

Comment: I'm using Qt 5.6 with GCC-4.9 on armeabiv7a on a Nexus6 with Android 5.5, same version of QtCreator. You should fill a Qt bug.

Comment: I did that yesterday: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-60297 :). Thanks anyway. There is even a guy that is saying that it happened to him with Qt 5.9 beta. Should the answers to this question be: It's a Qt bug?

Comment: Could become and answer once a Qt guy answered you and confirmed. They could also report you it's "not a bug" and propose a workaround. Wait and see.

Comment: Ok. Got it. Thanks

Comment: Looks like your bug is going to be fixed by Qt team

Comment: Yeah I saw that. I'm currently off the project that required this for the moment, but I would like to know if there was a workaround for this withouth having to wait for a new qt release. From what I've saw its only taking two lines of a file out of an if and that is it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed with aarelovich, that's a Qt bug.

Reported to Qt here: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-60297

And should apparently be fixed in coming release.

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer :) jajaj.